# Multiple constraint issues after updating to Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, warnings

I've been working on an app for quite some time now and after switching to Xcode 9, I got a lot of constraint warnings. I managed to fix them but now I keep getting the following 3 warnings on a regular basis:

1. Fixed width constraints may cause clipping.
2. Fixed leading / trailing constraints with a center constraint may cause clipping.
3. Trailing constraint is missing, which may cause overlapping with other views.

While the warnings make sense, I am unable to solve them, no matter what I try. And right now I have about 30 similar warnings.

For example, I have the following label:

[image]

with these constraints:

[image]

I have 5 identical labels on 5 separate VCs. All I need is to have the label and the text inside centered.

At first I had the leading and trailing constraint set to = 20 and had no issues. Now however I get a warning only on this label. I changed the leading and trailing to >= 20 yet this did not helped.

I have no problem with the other identical labels.

Another example is as follows:

I also have 2 labels, both placed inline:

[image]

The label on the left has the following constraints:

[image]

while the one on the right has these:

[image]

I get an "Trailing constraint is missing, which may cause overlapping with other views." warning and it makes sense since if there is too much text will be trimmed. However, adding a trailing constraint causes the following 2 warnings (lblMonthlyPayment is the label on the right):

[image]

Changing the constraint to >= or =< does not help.

In the third situation, I have a label that has a fixed height and takes the width of the element above (115pt) and I get "Fixed width constraints may cause clipping". Trying to set a 115 width constraint (virtually the same constraint) causes the same warning.

Again, it makes sense but I really need to give that label a fix width. Moreover, just like in the above situation, I have similar situations in the same app but no warning.

Any ideas?
I know this has been asked before and most of the answers found actually helped me get past these warnings but for some reasons these seem to stick, no matter what.

Comment: in your first image, you have set trailing and leading constraints and centerX. The warning is that you should use *either* leading and trailing or centerX. as they  are kind of doing the same thing but can also conflict. same thing with the other ones, they are fairly straight forward

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that. I already removed the centerX and still the same. I was just about to edit the post however. It seems that some warnings are not updating. For example, in the last situation I have 115 width, I changed it to 100 and the warning is the same, even after I restarted Xcode.

Comment: try running a build, normally helps

Comment: Tried Clean + Build multiple time, no luck. In fact, after upgrading to the last version of Xcode, I had 2 batches of warnings: one for code and one for constraints. Sometimes only those for constraints were visible and I had to clean / build and restart multiple times to get the other batch of warnings to show up so that I can fix them...